I cannot access the access token in SessionManager on Spotift IOS SDK
Even though everything is perfect and set up correctly, the accessToken is not returning.

I'm running my project in xCode on WmWare

I'm testing it on a real device, I'm connected to the PC via cable.

I am switching my application to Spotify, and after approval for the authorize process, it returns to the application, but the accessToken returns nil every time.

I am sure that my code verifier code challenge client id, client secret and redirect uri data are correct.


return Warning :
 Failed to initiate session: invalid_grant
Error domain: com.spotify.sdk.login
 Error code: 1
User Info: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "invalid_grant";
}

Please Help Me
